# I have no internet using virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I installed virtualbox and reinstalled it twice, but I still cannot connect to internet. I tried using everything possible, NAT, bridged adapters, host-only adpters, different drivers (only intel mt desktop works) and none of them work.

I do have a local connection when using a bridged adapter. I've tried using windows xp, vista, and linux - none of them can connect anywhere other than locally. I tried a port scan and compared it to the port scan on my actual PC and the only difference I found was that the VPC didn't find any ports on `192.168.1.1`.

If it helps, I'm using windows 10 and I'm on wifi.

The VPC keeps saying that the DNS and default gateway and some ip settings aren't configured properly. I have the ipv4 properties all set to automatic, but even after checking my routers connections and putting the exact same data in but manually, nothing changes.

Here are the options that allow me to connect locally

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 0):

I recently built some virtualbox Linux machines and had to configure all of this stuff.

I found it easiest to start your own NAT network using the command line tool. You can start a basic NAT network with the following command:

```
VBoxManage.exe natnetwork add --netname natnet1 --network "192.168.15.0/24" --enable
```

Keep in mind that unless you add some environment variables you will have to launch this command from the directory where the vboxmanage program is or provide the full path to the exe.

You can now use the list command to get the important information (like the gateway) about the network you just created with this command:

```
VBoxManage.exe natnetwork --netname natnet1 list
```

The documentation for vboxmanage can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html).

Make sure you connect the machine to the network you created before launching it.  It will be listed under nat network.

Now, you need to point Vista towards some DNS servers to resolve the hostnames. [This should get you started.](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228006967-Windows-Vista)

You can use whatever DNS servers you want to. Google has public servers at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Let me know if this helps at all and if anything was unclear.  Also, forgive me for any typos.